# How to get active visitors count at this moment on this page?

Tags: javascript, php, session, routes, yii2

I have a chat room and I want to show how many people are online exactly in this chat at this moment. User can join room with or without registation.

Comment: How are the users logged in the chat room?

Comment: For example by counting unique IP adresses or counting active sessions

Comment: @Nils IPs aren't people and can't reliably count/identify people.

Comment: User can join room with or without registation.

Comment: So how are users in a room managed?

Answer (score 1):

This is strongly dependant on the way you implement the chat room.
You could assign a chat-session id and timeout to each visitor, which gets expired over time and removed from a list.
This list will contain details on visitors, including the count.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick idea that has come to my mind (can be heavily customized and improved):

1) **Call a PHP script periodically** (for instance, once per a minute) through an AJAX call with a unique per-user ID. Like this, for example:

```
var visitorCounter = function() {
    $.get('audience_checker.php', {
      id: get_random_id() // inspiration below 
    });
}

setInterval(visitorCounter, 60000); // it gets called every 60000 ms = 1 minute
```

Take an inspiration [how to build a random ID generation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript). Or use the IP address.

2) **Now write the PHP script that will store IDs** from $_GET super-global variable in a database, with timestamp. If the ID already exists, just update the timestamp.

3) And finally, another script *statistics.php* can just **select those data from the database which are not older than a minute** bases on the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Of course will depend on your chat application logic but that's something I am using to count the users in my application. It is not perfect because you never know about your users if they don't log off.
You can add a new table to handle sessions:

```
`id`, `expire`, `data`, `user_id`, `last_write`
```

then change the configuration to save the sessions into this table instead of files.

```
        'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
        'writeCallback' => function ($session) {
            return [
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id,
                'last_write' => time(),
            ];
        },
    ],
```

then you can check the sessions in the last 5 minutes for instance

Hope it helps